# External Diff (Ctrl+D) not working anymore in sourcetree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I was using sourcetree 1.6.x (don't remember exactly which version) with git, and all of a sudden the "External Diff" right button command stopped working.

I was using this command forn the whole day, in the evening I left the computer on and stayed logged on, and on the next morning "External Diff" didn't work any more.

When I click on a modified file with the right button and then "External Diff", nothing happens.

I'm using the "System Default" Externall Diff Tool:

[image]

Then I upgraded to the lastest sourcetree version (1.9.6.1) hoping that might fix it, but the "External Diff" command is still not working.

The other functions of sourcetree work fine.

I also rebooted the computer, but it didn't help either.

Comment: `procmon` can tell what is the "system default" tool the UI tries to open and what it results in.

Comment: Does the external diff application work normally when launched through the Windows Start button?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev by fiddling with procmon, installing the latest version of beyond compare and changing the Diff settings in sourctree, the compare works again. Not really sure what actually happened here. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

"System default" apparently means whatever app you have [assigned](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144104%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to the `.diff` extension.

Due to the quirky nature of the [file type association system](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144104%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Windows (the further in the OS' history, the quirkier), an association can break or be overridden in a whole number of ways and for a whole number of reasons.
Reinstalling the app you have been using to open diffs (or using a command like "associate the program with `.diff` files" if it provides one) may fix the breakage. If not, search online about locating and fixing file type associations with tools and/or in registry (there's currently no one utility that can display and manage all the locations AFAICS).

Of course, you can set up a custom program in the dialog shown instead.